# SVM One-vs-One vs One-vs-ALL SVM

Tags: machine-learning, classification, svm, data-mining, unbalanced-classes

For an unbalanced dataset annotated by human annotators in which each item is assigned to different classes, what is the argument for and against using any of One-vs-One vs One-vs-ALL SVM classification approaches?

Comment: So, what do you think?

Comment: It's not a homework question. It's a design choice for a research problem and I have used one-vs-all but I have no argument in favor of any of these approaches. May be I posted it as a question that sounded like a homework.